# XLPagerTabStrip-Separator between controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

In XLPagerTabStrip, How can I add a separator between the view controllers, that will be shown only when scrolling?

Comment: Do you mean, separator between _tabs_ ?

Comment: @Hexfire Nope...Seperator for each controller in the container..I actually made a temporary work around like adding a UIView on the trailing edge of each controller,and show it only while scrolling through the container,as I dont want that to be seen when the user is idle in one controller.